# AssertionError ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.local_elast Worker group failed

Tags: python

While training with PyTorch in distributed mode, I encounter an error after approximately 10 minutes. The setup includes two NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 GPUs on a single machine. The error message is as follows:

```
AssertionError
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: 1) local_rank: 1 (pid: 60655) of binary: /home/xuts/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/bin/python3
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.local_elastic_agent:[default] Worker group failed
INFO:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.api:[default] Worker group FAILED. 3/3 attempts left; will restart worker group
INFO:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.api:[default] Stopping worker group
INFO:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.api:[default] Rendezvous'ing worker group
INFO:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.api:[default] Rendezvous complete for workers. Result:
  restart_count=1
  master_addr=127.0.0.1
  master_port=29500
  group_rank=0
  group_world_size=1
  local_ranks=[0, 1]
  role_ranks=[0, 1]
  global_ranks=[0, 1]
  role_world_sizes=[2, 2]
  global_world_sizes=[2, 2]
INFO:torch.distributed.elastic.agent.server.api:[default] Starting worker group
INFO:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing:Setting worker0 reply file to: /tmp/torchelastic_o95_6cs_/none_olhzm9ve/attempt_1/0/error.json
INFO:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing:Setting worker1 reply file to: /tmp/torchelastic_o95_6cs_/none_olhzm9ve/attempt_1/1/error.json
| distributed init (rank 1): env://
| distributed init (rank 0): env://
```

How can I solve the above problem? Please ask the spirits for advice.`